# Change the shape of a QLabel

Tags: pyqt5

I would like a little help, I am trying to generate a chat room but I would like that the QLabel that I use to show the messages had the form of a message container like this

[image]

And not only with the typical square shape of a QLabel

I tried to do the following:

```
def CreateLabel(self):
    image = QtGui.QPixmap("container.png")
    mask = image.createMaskFromColor(QtCore.Qt.red)

    self.Label = QLabel()
    self.Label.setText("Test Text")
    self.Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
    self.Label.setMask(mask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.text = text

        self.im = QImage('D:/_Qt/img/chat.png')
        self.resize(self.im.size())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        p = QPainter(self)
        p.drawImage(0, 0, self.im)

        self.drawText(event, p)                                 

    def drawText(self, event, p):
        p.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 4))
        p.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 12))
        p.drawText(event.rect(), Qt.AlignTop, self.text) 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        quit()


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text = """
                        How to draw a QLabel with chat image.
                    I would like a little help, I am trying to generate a chat 
                    room but I would like that the QLabel that I use to show 
                    the messages had the form of a message container like this.
                    """        

        self.label = Label(self.text)
        self.label.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
#    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]